# Delegate Protocol is not triggered in UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, delegates, protocols

I am trying to pass some data from LoginVC to MainStoreVC. I have implemented Delegate Protocol as supposed to but it seems to be not firing up.

Below is the LogInVC where I trigger the delegate

```
import UIKit


protocol RefreshCommercialInfo: AnyObject {
    func LoggedIn(userId: Int, token: String)
}

class LogInViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //private let headerView = AuthHeaderView(title: "Sign In", subTitle: "Sign in To Your Account")
    
    weak var delegate: RefreshCommercialInfo?
    
    private let userNameField = CustomTextField(fieldType: .username)
    private let passwordField = CustomTextField(fieldType: .password)
    
    private let tokenField = CustomTextField(fieldType: .username)
    
    private let singInButton = CustomButton(title: "Sign In", hasBackground: true, fontSize: .med)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        //title = "LogIn"
        self.setUpUI()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        self.singInButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapSignIn) , for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapSignIn() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        print("DEBUG PRINT: did tap Sign In")
        guard var Nametext = self.userNameField.text else { return }
        guard var Passwordtext = self.passwordField.text else { return }
        print("\(Nametext) account password is \(Passwordtext)")
        
        AuthenticationService().login(username: Nametext, password: Passwordtext) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let token):
                        defaults.setValue(token.access_token, forKey: "jsonwebtoken")
                        defaults.setValue(token.user_Id, forKey: "userId")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tokenField.text = token.access_token!
                            
                            //self.isAuthenticated = true
                        }
                        
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
        self.delegate?.LoggedIn(userId: 88 ?? 11, token: tokenField.text ?? "nill")
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }
    
    private func  setUpUI()
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        //self.view.addSubview(headerView)
        self.view.addSubview(userNameField)
        self.view.addSubview(passwordField)
        self.view.addSubview(tokenField)
        self.view.addSubview(singInButton)
        
        //headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        userNameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        passwordField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tokenField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        singInButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            //self.headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            //self.headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            //self.headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            //self.headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 222),
            
            self.userNameField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            //self.userNameField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerXAnchor),
            self.userNameField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            self.userNameField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55),
            self.userNameField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.85),
            
            self.passwordField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userNameField.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
            self.passwordField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userNameField.centerXAnchor),
            self.passwordField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55),
            self.passwordField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.85),
            
            self.tokenField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordField.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
            self.tokenField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordField.centerXAnchor),
            self.tokenField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55),
            self.tokenField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.85),
            
            self.singInButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tokenField.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
            self.singInButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tokenField.centerXAnchor),
            self.singInButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55),
            self.singInButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.85)
        ])
    }
}
```

And here is the where I describe it - StoreVC

```
class StoreViewController: UIViewController, FurnitureListViewDelegate, RefreshCommercialInfo {
    
    // Delegate Call
    func LoggedIn(userId: Int, token: String) {
        self.title = "NotStore"
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tokentext = token
            
            self.setUpView()
            self.GetTrendingProducts()
            self.GetCategories()
            self.populateAllProductsWithCategories()}
    }
    

    private var tokentext: String = ""
    private var ProductCategorizedDict: [Int : [FurnitureItem]] = [Int : [FurnitureItem]]()
    private var isUpdated: Bool = false
    private var ProductsUpdated: Bool = false
    private var trendingProducts : [TrendingFurnitureProduct] = [TrendingFurnitureProduct]()
    private var categories: [Category] = [Category]()
    
    
    private let furnitureListView = FurnitureListView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        title = "Store"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setUpView()
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard var tokentxt = defaults.string(forKey: "jsonwebtoken") else { return }
        self.tokentext = tokentxt
        
        
        
    }
    
    private func setUpView() {
           
           view.addSubview(furnitureListView)
           furnitureListView.delegate = self
           NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
               furnitureListView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
               furnitureListView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
               furnitureListView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor),
               furnitureListView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
           ])
       }

    
    func rmFurnitureListView(_ furnitureListView: FurnitureListView, didSelectFurniture furniture: TrendingFurnitureProduct) {
        print("choosing furniture event handler")
        let viewModel = FurnitureDetailViewViewModel(furniture: furniture)

        
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            let vc = FurnitureDetailViewController()
            vc.configure(with: viewModel)
            self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc , animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    func GetTrendingProducts() {

        }
        
        func GetCategories() {

        }
        
        func populateAllProductsWithCategories()
        {

        }
        
        
}
```

I can see complier hits my break point of self.delegate?.LoggedIn(userId: 88 ?? 11, token: tokenField.text ?? "nill")

but it does not fire it up on the side of StoreVC. I am not sure why - because i have implemented the protocol and have called it out by delegate.

Can you please point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

When  you present login  from `StoreViewController` make sure to set the delegate

```
let vc = LogInViewController()
vc.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of viewDidLoad of StoreVC, you need to make it the delegate , here is how you do it

```
let vc = LogInViewController()
vc.delegate = self
```

Now why we do this?

We do this as now the StoreVC view controller takes the responsibility to responds to messages generated by LogInViewController(), this is the whole logic of delegate pattern, make the view controller that takes the responsibility to perform certain task , the delegate and then when ever it receives any messages in our case when `didTapSignIn()` is fired it also triggers `LoggedIn(userId: Int, token: String)` which will have values in its parameter, that we can then use inside StoreVC.

Comment: I have added two lines in the viewDidLoad within StoreVC - and it is still not firing it up. I checked this in debug mode with break point set func LoggedIn() of StoreVC

Answer (score 0):

I believe your flow moves from LoginViewController to StoreViewController
and delegate pattern is used to send data in backward direction that is why nothing is happening.

Example how delegate pattern works

```
class LoginViewController:RefreshCommercialInfo {
    func moveToStoreViewController(){
        let vc = StoreViewController() //write code for pushing
        vc.delegate = self
    }
    func LoggedIn(userId: Int, token: String) {
        //some actions or manipulation
    }
}

Protocol RefreshCommercialInfo:AnyObject {
    func LoggedIn(userId: Int, token: String)
}

class StoreViewController {
    weak var delegate:RefreshCommercialInfo?
    func popViewController(){
        self.someFunction()
        self.navigationController.popViewController()
    }
    func someFunction(){
        if let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.LoggedIn(userId:7,token:"dfjghjchjshdj")
        }
    }
}
```